# android contact list UI

Tags: android, listview

[image]I want to implement list view similar to the contacts UI in android i.e alphabets list on right side of screen and section headers consists of starting letter, data is coming from database.

I have found few links but these are using `AlphabetIndexer` and not showing A-Z list on right side of screen. [This link](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/) shows how to create headers but these header are static I want to create headers dynamically means if I don't have data starting with letter 'B' no header should be created. below is screen shot of UI

```
                    ![contact listview screenshot][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Simple Section Adapter](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter) I have written. You need a layout for the header that mimics the contacts application and also another layout for the contacts list item. Here are a [few examples](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter/tree/09a9342e9e73cd39685e8e44fd47fd6902820d1d/src/com/mobsandgeeks/demo) as well.

Also the book example I have specified in the above mentioned link does exactly what you are looking for.